# Laravel custom Validation Rule on multiple fields and dealing with business logic

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I'm working on an endpoint that has data that is very dependant on each other to determine if it is valid. The data coming in will look something like this:

```
{
    job: 123
    activity: 345
    date: 2021-01-01
}
```

There are some checks I will need to do on individual fields, and that all makes sense to me. But I also need to do checks that involve multiple fields. For example, that an activity is available on a job. Or an activity is valid on a given date. For these kinds of validation, I need access to multiple fields, and as best I can tell you only really know about the field that you are validating.

So here is the rule class I want to make to check that an activity is valid on a given data

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;


use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ValidAcitivityOnDate implements Rule
{
    /**
     * @var Carbon
     */
    protected $date;

    public function __construct(Carbon $date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        //Some logic here based on the activity and date
        return false;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The activity is not valid for {$this->date->toDateString()}.';
    }
}
```

I then use the validator like this

```
$rule = new ValidAcitivityOnDate(new Carbon($request->input('date')));
$validator = Validator::make($request->input(), ["activity" => ["required", $rule]]);
$validatedData = $validator->validate();
```

So first question is if I am handling this multiple field validation properly? Should it be done by adding the additional field(s) in the constructor of the rule?

Second question would be if this is the correct approach? I have not used Laravel validators before, but they seem the logical place to put validation logic. But every example I have seen does not have validation dependent on multiple fields. The validation I have seen is more focused on "is the data in the correct form" where my validation is "does the data fulfill some business logic".

To further add to that, it is very likely that some of the validation will require service classes and repositories to get some of the information needed to check validation. I can pass those through the constructors as needed, but it feels like it could get messy quickly

I think the end solution will need to be a combination of service class methods and validators. These validation checks will be re-used in several places, and by the looks of it they will get messy quickly. So having a service class method to contain all that seems the right choice (and is what I had in mind before I was nudged towards validators anyway). But having the actual validation logic contained in validators seems like a good idea too.

I want to find out if I am off base here or not. Or should I leave validators to simple input checks, and the business logic validation should just sit in service classes?

Comment: If your code has more business logic you should move to Custom Rules. don't think twice. don't make your validation ugly without custom rule validations

Comment: There's a Form Request you can use it every controller actions

Comment: RE: custom rules, is the solution above using custom rules, or are they something entirely seperate? I was under the impression that the ValidAcitivityOnDate class I included was a custom rule, but not 100% sure.



RE: form requests, that may be an option. But I do need this validation to be available outside of controllers as well. At the very least, it will be needed by a queue job as well, along with it being re-used in several different controllers. So my focus right now is how to best encapsulate that base validation

Comment: Well, You can use Custom Rules and call it everywhere (controller with `validate()`), (repo, service; use `passes()` function as a condition). Maybe a Service that Validates data and you can call that service everywhere as well in your Custom Rules or Form Requests, did u get the idea?

Comment: @PsyLogic Right, I get what you are saying. The Rules are the right place for this validation logic, so put it there. You can then use it in the controllers with validate, or the services (or anywhere else) by calling passes. Looks like this going to be a orginizing idea for now, and hopefully we can get more of the extra niceness down the road

Comment: yes, your class ValidActivityOnDate is a custom rule and also yes, your approach is on the right track